# Matching Records with one additional Value from first table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables Tab1, Tab2 with one column “EmpID”

My first table has values A B C D E second table values are A B C.

Now I want all the common records from both tables(Value A B C) and one additional value from table 1(Value E). Is there any way to do this in SQL.

thanks
santhosha

Comment: Could you give us an actual example, what do you mean by additional value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is something like following:

```
-- giving you all values where empId is equal for Tab1 and Tab2
select t1.empId
from tab1 t1, tab2 t2
where t1.empId = t2.empId

-- union with your value for 'E'
union all
select t1.empid from tab1 t1 where t1.empid = 'E';
```